# If $N\models M=\cup\{M_\beta:\beta<\omega_1\}$ and $N\prec H(\theta)$ is countable, why is it true that $M\cap N=\cup\{M_\beta:\beta<N\cap \omega_1\}$

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I am going through Alan Dow's paper https://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v13/tp13102.pdf

I don't quite understand the last paragraph of the proof of theorem 3.1

Here is the setting:

$\{M_\beta:\beta<\omega_1\}$ is a continuous $\in$-chain of countable elementary submodels and their union is $M$ (so $|M|=\omega_1$), where $M\prec H(\theta)$. We have a countable $N\prec H(\theta)$ where $\{M_\beta:\beta<\omega_1\}$ and $M$ are both in $N$. Let $\delta=N\cap \omega_1$.

If $N\models M=\cup\{M_\beta:\beta<\omega_1\}$, why do we have that $M\cap N=\cup\{M_\beta:\beta<\delta\}$? Is this a trivial result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement "$N \models M = \bigcup\{M_\beta : \beta < \omega_1\}$" can be written as $$N \models \forall x (x \in M \leftrightarrow \exists \beta (\beta < \omega_1 \wedge x \in M_\beta)$$

The $\omega_1$ here needs to be interpreted as the set that $N$ thinks is $\omega_1$, because we are evaluating the formula in $N$.  That is, the $\omega_1$ above is, in the real world, $\omega_1^N$, and $\omega_1^N = \delta$.

When interpreting "$N \models \forall x \ldots$" the quantifier ranges only over elements of $N$.  Thus the above statement really says $$\forall x \in N (x \in M \leftrightarrow \exists \beta (\beta < \delta \wedge x \in M_\beta)$$  This is equivalent to $N \cap M = \bigcup\{M_\beta : \beta < \delta\}$.